# Как расширить сайт для более удобного отображения информации?

Tags: yii, css

Стандартная тема имеет в ширину 900 пикселей и 2 колонки, а статики там вообще с одной. Как можно расширить сайт для более удобного отображения информации и как, предположим, сделать 3 колонку слева (например, карта сайта)? Как и куда копать?

Comment: Копайте в сторону папки под названием protected/views/layouts, в этой папке лежат файлы, которые делают 1-2 колонки в зависимости от функционала, а если есть проблема с css, то есть [такой extension][1]

[1]: http://docs.siquo.net/yii-bootstrap/

Comment: А я уже думал, что трехколоночные сайты умерли. Как раз с трех колонок инфа плохо и воспринимается.

Comment: 3 колонки так для примера привел. просто хотел понять как тот или иной функционал добавить

Answer (score 1):

http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/03/yii-yii-for-dummies.html

В обминку с firebug`ом нашел, откуда у css ноги растут.

Answer (score 0):

Копать надо в css-файл, подключенный к сайту, и в книгу по html+css. Или смотреть в браузере с отладчиком, как сделано сейчас, и пробовать по аналогии делать самостоятельно. Но все же лучше первый вариант.